# Ubuntu Mail Server unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, email-server

I have been trying to setup a mail server in ubuntu using this tutorial: http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/index.html

I have completed the basic configurations (I havent reached the extend part yet)

So, I have used telnet and the following works:

- send email to gmail
- send mail to itself
- forward the mail it receives (I have forwarded the mail I receive to an external account for testing purposes, so the above step forwards the email to another gmail account)

So my problem is I cannot send mail from gmail, I get '530 530 5.7.1 Invalid Address'.

All of what I have tried is:

- I have tried pinging my mail server from another pc on the same network, cant find the server.
- I disabled the router's firewall, forwarded the port and set up my mail server as an exposed host.
- Disabled shorewall on my mail server.
- Changed the shorewall policies to allow everything in.

At each of the above steps I tried sending an email from gmail to my mail server and I still get the same error.

I am really not sure what is happening, and am clueless of what to do.

Comment: Is your fqdn well configured?
Do you have a reverse host configured?

Comment: Thank you for kind of pointing me in the right direction. I had problems with the fqdn as well as the MX/SPF records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just browsed through the link you gave and your question also mentions that - "I have tried pinging my mail server from another pc on the same network, cant find the server."

So it must be a DNS problem. On command line type

```
nslookup <your mail server fully qualified domain name>
```

like

```
nslookup mail.yahoo.com
```

If you get proper IP address of server then try using

```
dig -t mx <mail domain name>
```

like

```
dig -t mx yahoo.com
```

If you see IPs in both nslookup and dig then fine, else it is confirmed DNS problem.

Comment: Thank you also for kind of pointing me in the right direction. I had problems with the fqdn as well as the MX/SPF records. I am able to find the server now, however now the emails are bouncing back saying: Connection timed out.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/var/log/mail.log` to see exactly what the mail server is doing; paste the relevant entries in your question if they don't make sense to you.  Also, copies of your config files would probably help.

Comment: which config files do you need me to post?they are the same as the ones on the link (tutorial) posted above

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you try out this :-http://jitamitra.blogspot.com/2009/03/configure-postfix-postfixadmin-dovecot.html

I found this is very easy way of configuration,Once you done you can customize it as you need, Just have look at this.